# what is the best way to deploy simple flask rest api

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

this is my first time using `flask-rest-api` and my server is `centOS` and on this server I have `Apache2`

my question is: do I need to deploy on `apache` or `flask` it's self works?

Comment: By default flask uses wsgi for running the server. Try dockerizing the flask app, if you don't want it to interfere with the apache one or anything.

Comment: @kite how can I deploy that on `centOS`?

Comment: There are many ways of deploying your flask app - try reading this good article about [wsgi](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/what-is-wsgi-web-server-gateway-interface-ed2d290449e) you will understand, but if you want to do it with apache there are many articles like [this online](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps).